# converting AndroidManifest.xml to Package.appxmanifest

Tags: android, asp.net

I am trying to convert AndroidManifest.xml file of android application to corresponding Package.appxmanifest file of windows 8.

There is one tag `<service>` in AndroidManifest.xml so that I have mapped to

```
<Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks">
    <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="systemEvent" />
    </BackgroundTasks>
</Extension>
```

but my question is that

(i) so which task type I should add to `Package.appxmanifest`?

(ii) There are `<Extention>` tag with so many categories.so on which basis I should add that `<Extention>`tag with category in Package.appxmanifest.?

(iii)There are many permission type in xml so for that is it desirable to add  tag or only I should map it with `<capabilities>` in Package.appxmanifest.